# Display the numbers in the table from largest to smallest (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I want to make a table that is separated by pages, and the numbers in the form will not start counting from a new page because of a different page. However, it will count from beginning to end.

For example, this is the first page:

```
10 XXX
9 XXX
8 XXX
7 XXX
6 XXX
```

And this is the second page:

```
5 XXX
4 XXX
3 XXX
2 XXX
1 XXX
```

However, I could not let it counite counting, and now it happened a problem when I change to the next page:

The counter still like this:

```
10 XXX
9 XXX
8 XXX
7 XXX
6 XXX
5 XXX
```

Note: the post **Notice** always appears above, then after that is a normal post.

This my code:

```js
const rawData = [
  {
    writer: "Admin",
    post_admin: true,
    new_post: false,
    title: "Test",
    slug: "test",
    code: "230109000001",
    created_at: "2023-01-09 15:56:59",
    view: 3,
    share: 1,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 4,
  },
  {
    writer: "Dafni Lanahtadya",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "pink",
    slug: "pink",
    code: "230120000112",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 13:19:23",
    view: 2,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
  {
    writer: "Dafni Lanahtadya",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "weather 3",
    slug: "weather-3",
    code: "230120000111",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 13:16:32",
    view: 1,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
  {
    writer: "Dafni Lanahtadya",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "weather 2",
    slug: "weather-2",
    code: "230120000110",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 13:15:10",
    view: 2,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
  {
    writer: "Dafni Lanahtadya",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "weather",
    slug: "weather",
    code: "230120000109",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 13:13:47",
    view: 1,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
  {
    writer: "Putri Seprina",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "postingan 19 saya",
    slug: "postingan-19-saya",
    code: "230120000102",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 10:08:46",
    view: 4,
    share: 1,
    jumlah_like: 1,
    jumlah_komen: 5,
  },
  {
    writer: "Putri Seprina",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "postingan 1 saya",
    slug: "postingan-1-saya",
    code: "230120000056",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 10:00:38",
    view: 1,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
  {
    writer: "Dafni Lanahtadya",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "57",
    slug: "57",
    code: "230120000045",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 09:58:37",
    view: 0,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
  {
    writer: "Dafni Lanahtadya",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "58",
    slug: "58",
    code: "230120000044",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 09:58:22",
    view: 0,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
  {
    writer: "Dafni Lanahtadya",
    post_admin: false,
    new_post: false,
    title: "59",
    slug: "59",
    code: "230120000043",
    created_at: "2023-01-20 09:58:14",
    view: 0,
    share: 0,
    jumlah_like: 0,
    jumlah_komen: 0,
  },
];

function Index() {
  const [listSubPost, setListSubPost] = useState(rawData);
  const [countPage, setCountPage] = useState(0);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [dataCount, setDataCount] = useState(31);
  const [dataAdminCount, setDataAdminCount] = useState(0);
  const [initialPage, setInitialPage] = useState(1);

  const setPage = (array, page_size, page_number) => {
    // human-readable page numbers usually start with 1, so we reduce 1 in the first argument
    setListSubPost(
      array.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size)
    );
  };

  let _indexUser = 0;
  let _countAll = dataCount - dataAdminCount;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <table
          aria-label="Example static collection table"
          style={{
            height: "auto",
            minWidth: "100%",
            overflowX: "auto",
          }}
        >
          <thead>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>TITLE</td>
            <td>WRITER</td>
            <td>DATE</td>
            <td>LIKES</td>
            <td>VIEWS</td>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {listSubPost.map((item, index) => {
              if (!item?.post_admin) {
                _indexUser = _indexUser + 1;
              }
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>
                    {item?.post_admin
                      ? "Notice"
                      : _countAll -
                        (_indexUser - 2) -
                        Math.ceil(currentPage / perPage)}
                  </td>
                  <td>{item.title}</td>
                  <td>{item.writer}</td>
                  <td>{item.created_at}</td>
                  <td>{item.jumlah_like}</td>
                  <td>{item.view}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <button onClick={() => setPage(rawData, 5, 1)}>page 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPage(rawData, 5, 2)}>page 2</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your code and provide a [mre].

Comment: You're not paging properly. Instead of adding 1 to the page state you need to update with `(page number - 1) * record limit`. And you'll need to sort your data if you want the records to be 1 - 10, for example.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] as text in the question, not a link to your code. And add all logs, error messages and other texts as text, not as image. Stack Overflow isn't Instagram. People want to copy and search text.

Comment: It looks like the odd way you're calculating the ids. If you just want to have a list of `post_admin` posts why not `filter` on them. Maybe have a set of checkboxes to show only those posts that you want?

Comment: in planning it requires displaying posts simultaneously created by the admin and posts created by the user

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for the answer,

after several hours of searching for the right formula, I finally found the solution.
this for my formula at column **Number**

```
{item?.post_admin ? 'Notice' : (dataCount - ((currentPage - 1) * perPage)) - index}
```

if someone search about my problem or same with my question :)